# Upgrade 14.04 to 16.04, get black screen with blinking underscore and 5 purple boxes with red/white dots in them

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, upgrade

I have finally gotten around to upgrading to 16.04 from 14.04, and I just restarted my computer for the first time under 16.04.  Unfortunately, the OS failed to boot.  [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzq4U.jpg) is what the screen looks like (the white dots change back and forth to red from left to right).

Any help would be fantastic, I'd like to get back to using my desktop asap.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *I'd like to get back to using my desktop asap*... The fastest way is reinstalling Ubuntu.